# Find filename ending from arraylist

Tags: python, arrays

**Program:** I'm trying to create a sorting program for multiple PDF files. Therefore I have a folder with PDFs listet for example like this: 001-x; 001-y1; 001-y2; 001-y3; 001-z; 002-x; 002-y1; 002-y2; ... I am running through all file names in the folder and also have array named "sort_by" (for the elements see code below). **Problem:** I now want to cycle through the array of files and move the current file to a folder if the file name includes any of the elements of sort_by. **My Code so far:**

```py
sort_by = ["x", "z"]
my_path = 'some path on PC'

for root, directories, file in os.walk(my_path):
    for file in file:
        # this is the part that doesnt work
        if file.endswith(sort_by):
        # do something
```

I know that something like `if file.endswith(x) or file.endswith(y):` would work but I want the array to be adjustable in content and length. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `any()` function:

```
if any(file.endswith(ending) for ending in sort_by):
    # do something
```